# -webkit- and -moz-border-radius does not work on tables?

Tags: webkit, gecko, css

This works

```
div {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:30px;
}
```

This does not work

```
table {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:30px;
}
```

Does anyone know how to use -moz and -webkit to work on tables?

Answer (score 8):

> [**5.6. Effect on Tables**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius)
>
> The ‘border-radius’ properties do
>   apply to ‘table’ and ‘inline-table’
>   elements. When ‘border-collapse’ is
>   ‘collapse’, the UA may apply the
>   border-radius properties to ‘table’
>   and ‘inline-table’ elements, but is
>   not required to. In this case not only
>   must the border radii of adjacent
>   corners not intersect, but the
>   horizontal and vertical radii of a
>   single corner may not extend past the
>   boundaries of the cell at that corner
>   (i.e. the cell's other corners must
>   not be affected by this corner's
>   border-radius). If the computed values
>   of the border radii would cause this
>   effect, then the used values of all
>   the border radii of the table must be
>   reduced by the same factor so that the
>   radii neither intersect nor extend
>   past the boundaries of their
>   respective corner cells.
>
> *The effect of border-radius on
>   internal table elements is undefined
>   in CSS3 Backgrounds and Borders, but
>   may be defined in a future
>   specification. CSS3 UAs should ignore
>   border-radius properties applied to
>   internal table elements when
>   ‘border-collapse’ is ‘collapse’.*

Comment: It's all about the `border-collapse` that's what prevented the border radius in my case.